# Checking string in the particular time format

Tags: c#, time, timespan, tryparse

I'm trying check is string(textBox1.Text) on the time format "hh:mm:ss", for send that string, as time parameter, in Sql query. I use TimeSpan.TryParseExact method:

```
        TimeSpan check;
        TimeSpan.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "hh:mm:ss", null, out check);
        if(check==null)   MessageBox.Show("incorrect time");
        else...
```

But when I write to textbox 11 to the table adding the time 00:00:11 (11 seconds). I want so it's was incorrect time, correct is 00:00:11 line. How to do it's right?

Comment: I have no idea what behaviour you are looking for...

Comment: The test should be `if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(...)) { ... }` since `TimeSpan` is a struct and therefore is not nullable. Your code does not compile! How can the result be incorrect?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - `TimeSpan` can be checked for `null` as the `==` operator is overridden and implicitly converts the struct to a `Nullable<T>` type. That code should compile fine (assuming `else...` is properly replaced)

Comment: OK, I tried it. It does effectively compile, but the reason is a different one: the `TimeSpan` will be boxed, i.e. it will be converted to an `object`; however this object will never be `null` and therefore `check==null` will always be false! You can as well test `5 == null`. You will get a warning saying: *"The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type '<null>'"*.

Comment: The reason is the same as it gets boxed because it's converted to a `TimeSpan?` type. Nullables do this under the hood which is why it's possible to check value types for null. You're right that the code snippet above would always result in false (`check == null`) but I was just clarifying that checking a `TimeSpan` value for null is valid code, even if redundant as in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use controls that are suitable for the task you're trying to do. For example, in this case, it may be easier and more consistent for users to use a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control instead of a TextBox.

Set the DateTimePicker's `Format` property to `Time` and the `ShowUpDown` property to `true`. You can also do this in code as shown below.

```
myTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
myTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

You can also use the [CustomFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to format the way you want the time displayed. If you use `CustomFormat`, you'll want to do this:

```
myTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom; //instead of Time as above
myTimePicker.CustomFormat = "hh:mm:ss"; //or whichever format you want
```

Comment: I try it, but how to not show calendar on the right part of DateTimePicker?

Comment: Set the `ShowUpDown` property to `true`. You can do this in the designer or in code as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to use the result of TryParseExact that is a boolean true if the conversion succed. Also notice that there is a [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx) for hours/minutes/seconds

```
TimeSpan check;
if(TimeSpan.TryParseExact("09:00:01", "g", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out check))
    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
```

**EDIT**
Looking at your comment below then probably you need a [custom timespan format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
TimeSpan check;
if(TimeSpan.TryParseExact("09:00:01", @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out check))
    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
```

Comment: I try test a string "111" my result it's "111.00:00:00" on check.ToString() (111 days), but I ask to show "Incorrect" result. This working right only test like "11:10" giving result "11:10:00".

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Demo
    {
        /* ... */
        readonly Regex timeFormat = new Regex(@"^(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        public bool IsTimeFormatValid(string time)
        {
            return timeFormat.IsMatch(time);
        }
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Regex Example: http://regex101.com/r/qR3qV6/1

NB: Timespan.TryParse aims to convert a string to a timespan.  TryParseExact does the same; only it allows you to specify a culture/expected format (it's poorly named as it doesn't force the format to be exactly what you've specified).

These methods want to convert if possible; so they're quite generous in what they'll accept.  They're not designed to validate the format; only to make a best attempt at converting the given data based on a given format.  In this case given a string lacking information they're assuming that hours and minutes not being specified means they're 0 valued, so they treat your data as seconds.

Using a regex avoids this issue - it says you want to check the format rather than just see if the system can make a guess at what the data in that format means.